# How do I generate a list of all REST endpoints from a WADL file?

Tags: python, xml, rest, xml-parsing

I have several wadl files from a web application, and I need to generate a list of all valid REST endpoint URLS from that wadl file.
I have tried using packages like wadlib, wadl2py and wadl2swagger, but they all give me errors saying the wadl file is not valid.

The file is being generated by jasper 2.

I need a list of all endpoint URLS and the valid methods/parameters for each endpoint.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly these files are **XML** files.

So if the libraries didn't help you, you can try use [Python XML modules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) to handle as XML and you can check the specification [here](https://github.com/javaee/wadl) or see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language).

I think that extracting the **Resources names** from theses files can be pretty simple if you have a good experience with Python.

Here is an example:

https://gist.github.com/klassmann/1e75d4a640bfbc766f8058f728267553